# Linearly independent subset of a quotient ring as a module

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, modules, quotient-spaces

Consider the quotient ring $M:=\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ as a module over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\overline{f(x)}\in M$ nonzero. Is it true that $\{\overline{f(x)},\overline{xf(x)}\}$ is linearly independent?

*My attempt*:

We let

$$k_1f(x)+k_2xf(x)=g(x)(x^2+x+1)$$

for some $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{R},g(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Suppose LHS is nonzero.

The LHS is equal to $f(x)(k_1+k_2x)$ which must be divisible by $h(x):=x^2+x+1$. As $h(x)$ does not factor in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the nonzero $k_1+k_2x$ is relatively prime to $h(x)$, and hence $f(x)$ is divisible by $h(x)$, contradicting that $\overline{f(x)}$ is nonzero in $M$. Thus, LHS must be zero and as $f(x)$ again cannot be zero, $k_1=k_2=0$. So, yes, our set is linearly indepentend. Q.E.D.

1. Is the above reasoning correct?
2. I am not sure whether I can use the term *relatively prime* in polynomial. Even if it is OK, are there other ways to say what I mean above?

Thank you so much for all suggestions.

Comment: You also can use *coprime* for polynomials. Yes, your reasoning is correct. However, you should explicitly make the hypothesis, from the beginning, that $k_1, k_2$ are not both $0$.

Comment: I am assuming nonzero LHS, but I think your way is clearer conclusion-wise. Thank you!